# Which parts of my computer do I need to replace along with a new Processor

Tags: cpu, power-supply, cpu-cooler

About a year ago I build a computer with an intel i3-8100 processor.

However I have decided to replace it with the intel i7-8700k processor, so I wold like to know if I need to replace any of the hardware of my current setup.
What I'm worried about is if need a higher voltage for the power supply or a better cpu cooler.

This are the specifications of my computer:

-Grafic card: ASUS GeForce® GT 710 2GB DDR3.

-Motherboard: ASUS ATX PRIME Z370-P, S-1151, Intel Z370.

-CPU air cooler: Cooler Master Hyper T2, 92mm, 800-2800RPM.

-Hard drive: Toshiba P300 3.5" 2TB, SATA III, 7200RPM, 64MB Cache.

-Computer case: Thermaltake Versa N26 con Ventana, Midi-Tower.

-Power supply: Gigabyte PB500 80 PLUS Bronze, 20+4 pin ATX, 120mm, 500W.

Also it has 2 RAM Kingston HyperX FURY Black DDR4, 2133MHz, 8GB.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are wanting to do is replace your CPU then your 500W PSU and current CPU cooler looks to be fine.

Under heavy load the cooler might get a bit loud according to Amazon reviews, but it should work. You could get a better one if you wanted it quieter.

When changing CPU you should also replace any thermal paste on the CPU cooler.

The rest of your setup looks good for that kind of setup.

If you were going to replace your graphics card with a 1070 or 1080 then you might need to look at upgrading your PSU.

Comment: For a bit more explanation, this is an easy swap because the i3-8100 and the i7-8700k have the same CPU socket type. If the socket types did not match, a new motherboard would have to be purchased that has the same socket type as the new CPU.